# REST API Ajax call using angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ajax, rest

```
app.controller('AjaxController', function ($scope,$http){
  $http.json('mc/rest/candidate/pddninc/list',{
    params: {
        callback:'JSON_CALLBACK'
    }
  }).
  success(function (data, status, headers, config){
    if(angular.isArray(data.candidateDetails)){
        $scope.reports = data.candidateDetails;
    }
    else{
        $scope.reports = [data.candidateDetails];
    }
    consol.log(data);
  }).
  error(function (data, status, headers, config){});
});
```

error: `$http.json` is not a function. 
I am trying to print a data using REST API with angular.

Comment: instead of $http.json do you mean .get? or .jsonp?

Comment: I think he's trying to do a JSONP request, hence the method should be `$http.jsonp()`, instead of `$http.json()`.

Comment: Did you look it up in the `$http` documentation? Would have figured problem out quickly if you did

Comment: I am trying to get data from local domain using REST API and angular so instead of $http.jsonp(), what can i use.?

Comment: json isn't a request type, it's a datatype. you should be using get for a get request, or jsonp for a jsonp request. it sounds like you need a get request.

Answer (score -1):

The method you have to call when doing a JSONP request is `$http.jsonp()`.

See the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp).

```
$http.jsonp('mc/rest/candidate/pddninc/list', {
    params: {
      callback:'JSON_CALLBACK'
    }
}).success(...)
```